# Create multiple views inside a schema - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view, sql-server-2008-r2

How can I create multiple views inside the `CREATE SCHEMA` statement?

I want to create a `SCHEMA`, and create two views inside it in the same statement, so all those statements work as a one unit? Succeed or fail together!

From MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189462.aspx

> "CREATE SCHEMA can create a schema, the tables and views it contains,
>   and GRANT, REVOKE, or DENY permissions on any securable in a single
>   statement. CREATE SCHEMA transactions are atomic. If any error occurs
>   during the execution of a CREATE SCHEMA statement, none of the
>   specified securables are created and no permissions are granted."

,

How can I do this? I tried this:

```
CREATE SCHEMA [MYSCHEMA] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    CREATE VIEW [VIEW1]
    AS 
        SELECT [ID]
               ,[NAME]
                FROM [dbo].[TABLE1]
        /* Here is the Problem */
        GO

        CREATE VIEW [VIEW2]
        AS
        SELECT [ID]
               ,[NAME]
                FROM [dbo].[TABLE2]
        GO
```

If I include a `GO` statement just after first view creation, then script runs but second view `VIEW2` is created under the `dbo` schema, not under `MYSCHEMA`, and doesn't run as a single unit either.

If I remove the `GO` after the first view, then it gives an error saying

> *CREATE VIEW must be the first statement of a batch*

for the second `CREATE VIEW` statement.

How do I solve this and create both views as a part of `CREATE SCHEMA` statement?

Comment: If you want to put `View1` into `MySchema` - just prefix the view name with the schema upon creation: `CREATE VIEW MySchema.View1 AS ...`

Comment: @marc_s, yes I know that, but then they wont act as a single unit. Doing my way will make sure either everything is created or nothing is. Which is important to me in this case.

Comment: @marc_s, taken from MSDN "CREATE SCHEMA can create a schema, the tables and views it contains, and GRANT, REVOKE, or DENY permissions on any securable in a single statement. CREATE SCHEMA transactions are atomic. If any error occurs during the execution of a CREATE SCHEMA statement, none of the specified securables are created and no permissions are granted.", that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
CREATE SCHEMA [MYSCHEMA] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]

CREATE VIEW [VIEW1] AS SELECT [ID], [NAME] FROM [dbo].[TABLE1]
CREATE VIEW [VIEW2] AS SELECT [ID], [NAME] FROM [dbo].[TABLE2]
GO
```

Comment: I am not sure why you got a downvote, this works. I just tested this on sql server 2008 r2

Comment: @bluefeet: surprisingly - yes, this does seem to work just fine, and it does seem to create those views in the new schema. You never stop learning :-)

Comment: Thanks guys :) I did test it before posting.

Comment: @marc_s I didn't think it would work either, that is why I tested it.

Comment: @kgu87: not everyone does :-) +1 for you!

Comment: Didn't know that either. The `CREATE VIEW` is considered part of the `CREATE SCHEMA` statement [CREATE SCHEMA can create a schema, the tables and views it contains, and GRANT, REVOKE, or DENY permissions on any securable in a single statement. This statement must be executed as a separate batch. Objects created by the CREATE SCHEMA statement are created inside the schema that is being created.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189462.aspx)

Comment: @kgu87, yup it works, Thanks guys, why I got 'create view must be the first...' error was because I added a ';' after the first CREATE VIEW statement thinking that it seperates statements better, but not only its not necessary, it caused all the problems